# Ubuntu Core images for Artik 530 / 530s

Tags: samsung, ubuntu-core

Are there any plans on providing Ubuntu Core images for Artik 530 and Artik 530s?

The images listed in https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/artik-5-10 seem to be for Artik 520 and don't boot on 530/530s.

Comment: Have you checked the prerequisites for the 530 core?

Comment: Even digikey ( https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/ARTIK+5 ) does not have images for 530. So it is too new (or number of developers is small).